# Change volume configuration in docker-compose without losing the data

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

My docker-compose has a data container which isn't mapped to a local directory in the host machine, and I want to change it from:

```
volumes:
  - /var/www/html
```

to

```
volumes:
  - /html:/var/www/html
```

But when I will restart the container, it will remove the current data container and replace it with a new one.

I know that the container is actually still there, but is there an easy way to do it without the creation of a new data container.

My docker-compose version is 1.7.1 (under boot2docker).

Thanks.

Comment: isn't `/var/www/html` actually on the host machine?

Comment: No.. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/volumes-volumedriver

Comment: thanks, i wasn't sure about docker-compose syntax for this.

Answer (score 2):

Try at your own risk:

- create your host directory `/html`as you wish
- `docker inspect {container_name} | grep Source` and grab your volume path on the host system. It'll be something like `/var/lib/docker/volumes/abdb15a2eff[...]/_data`
- copy the content of that directory to your host directory
- recreate the container as you wish.

Comment: Sounds very reasonable. I will try that :)

Comment: I tried this and I can confirm it's working fine. Container had to be destroyed and another one created for it to work, but no data loss.

Answer (score 0):

One safe way to do this is to create a backup of the data from inside the Docker image. Then restore that backup to the directory on your host machine. The [Docker Volumes Tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/) mentions a process like this near the bottom.

Here's how you'd do it:

First, mount a directory from your host machine into the container if you don't already have one mounted in. Maybe a volume like `./:/backup`. Next, run a backup command like this:

```
docker-compose run service-name tar czvf /backup/html_data.tar.gz /var/www/html
```

Now you have `html_data.tar.gz` in your current directory. Extract it wherever you want and be on your way!

(I'm assuming, based on the way you indicated your volumes, that you're using docker-compose. The process is similar for vanilla Docker.)

---

**Alternate approach, with `--volumes-from`**

Get the name (or hash) of the container with the data you want to copy. You can do this with `docker ps`. For this example, let's call it `container1`. Now run this command to back up its data:

```
docker run --rm --volumes-from container1 -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu:latest tar czvf /backup/html_data.tar.gz /var/www/html
```

Note that the image you use (`ubuntu:latest`) is not important as long as it can tar things.

Comment: For that, I will need to use an additional container, because changing the data container's volumes section will replace it with a new one. Am I wrong here?

Comment: Hmm... I don't know; I'd have to try it. If editing the volumes doesn't work, you could take an equivalent approach with `--volumes-from`. I'll add details above.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I think as well. The previous answer is more relevant to my uae case, but that's handy too. Thanks!